# Orbeon 4.9 strange client-side javascript error

Tags: javascript, orbeon, xforms

Another migration issue. I have changed orbeon forms version from 3.8 to 4.9.

One of my xforms isn't working after migration, this button freezes form with "xforms-loading-loading" span visible. There are no errors on the server side. Both submissions from this action are getting WSDL/SCHEMA from exist and replaces two xform instances. It is working correctly as I can see with inspector. The only error i can see is Javascript Error "TypeError: "spanContainer is undefined" from line 120 orbeon...*js. spanContainer.appendChild(templateClone) this is the part of code that crashes my application.

`<xf:trigger ref="instance('page')/edition-valid">
                        <xf:label>EDIT</xf:label>
                        <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                            <xf:send submission="get-wsdl" />
                            <xf:send submission="get-schema" />
                            <xf:action if="not(instance('schema')//xsd:appinfo[text()='imported'])">
                                <xf:setvalue ref="instance('page')/edition/operation"
                                    value="instance('wsdl')//wsdl:portType[1]/wsdl:operation[1]/@name" />
                                <xf:setvalue ref="instance('page')/edition/cdm"
                                    value="if (instance('page')/edition/adapter='') then 'true' else ()" />
                                <xf:toggle case="edition" />
                            </xf:action>
                        </xf:action>
                    </xf:trigger>`

What is wrong?

Comment: spanContainer.appendChild(templateClone) this is the part of code that crashes my application

Comment: please edit that into your question, people don't always read comments.

Comment: This looks a duplicate of http://discuss.orbeon.com/Orbeon-Forms-application-migration-from-3-8-to-4-9-td4660085.html.